# How to extract specific values using a query?

Tags: sql, extract

I want to extract some value using a query, but it beats me everytime: In the picture below i draw my table content. [image] . All of the information you need, it is in the picture. I want to extract the following values : Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4 - where name = "T1". How can I do that? thx

Comment: It's unclear what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need is a [self join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm). The query will look like this:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM test a, test b
WHERE a.parentID = b.id AND b.name="T1";
```

Comment: Wow... nice guess (about OP's need). hehe